# How to Select All Continuous rows joining by begin and end date

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a situation where I have multiple rows in a table but they can be assigned to a common name id

| NAMEID | ID | STARTDATE | ENDDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10960 | 1 | 17-FEB-20 | 17-FEB-20 |
| 11210 | 2 | 17-FEB-20 | 18-FEB-20 |
| 10960 | 3 | 19-FEB-20 | 21-FEB-20 |
| 10960 | 4 | 21-FEB-20 | 02-MAR-20 |
| 11461 | 5 | 21-FEB-20 | 02-MAR-20 |
| 10960 | 6 | 01-MAR-20 | 06-MAR-20 |
| 10960 | 7 | 02-MAR-20 | 04-MAR-20 |

let's say I want to query by ID 7 and name_id 10960
I want to select rows where ID 7,4,3 because these are connecting records based on start and end date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to get all related rows.

For example:

```
with
n (nameid, id, startdate, enddate) as (
  select nameid, id, startdate, enddate from t where id = 7 -- starting row
 union all
  select t.nameid, t.id, t.startdate, t.enddate
  from n
  join t on t.nameid = n.nameid and t.enddate = n.startdate
)
select * from n;
```

Result:

```
 NAMEID  ID  STARTDATE  ENDDATE   
 ------- --- ---------- --------- 
 10960   7   02-MAR-20  04-MAR-20 
 10960   4   21-FEB-20  02-MAR-20 
 10960   3   19-FEB-20  21-FEB-20
```

See example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=09bb25ca21230e798ab885110bcc72eb).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONNECT BY` to return the rows by selecting your starting point and limiting which `nameid`s you want traversed.

```sql
    SELECT *
      FROM names
CONNECT BY enddate = PRIOR startdate AND nameid = PRIOR nameid
START WITH id = 7;
```

```
   NAMEID    ID    STARTDATE      ENDDATE
_________ _____ ____________ ____________
    10960     7 02-MAR-20    04-MAR-20
    10960     4 21-FEB-20    02-MAR-20
    10960     3 19-FEB-20    21-FEB-20
```